# push:false behaviour in worklight jsonstore

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

Simple question :

if I add documents with push:false to a collection linked to an adapter and then delete them, will they be marked dirty for deleting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `getAllDirty` (Worklight Version == v6.2) or `getPushRequired` (Worklight Version < v6.2) APIs after the operations (`add`, `remove`) to see their state. If the change is not tracked (add w/o tracking the change, remove) you will not get a document back. In that case the intent is that instead of telling the backed "add this document, then remove it" the API just doesn't tell the server about the document. It's a bit more efficient than sending a change over the network that will just get removed.

Otherwise, if the change is tracked as it's the case for `add(doc)` you will get back something like this as one of the elements of the array returned:

```
{_id: 1,
  json: {id: 1, ssn: '111-22-3333', name: 'Carlos'},
  _operation: 'add',
  _dirty: '1395774961,12902'}
```

Where `_operation` is the last operation performed. When using `push` (deprecated in Worklight v6.2) it will send that document to the adapter procedure noted in the `_operation` field (e.g. add => add procedure). The documentation [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_external_data.html?lang=en) covers how to work with external data in Worklight v6.2. The API documentation is [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.JSONStore.html?cp=SSZH4A_6.2.0%2F10-0-0-1-16&lang=en) and [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.JSONStore.JSONStoreInstance.html?cp=SSZH4A_6.2.0%2F10-0-0-1-17&lang=en). There are also examples of the various APIs [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_examples.html?lang=en). Feature requests [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25).

Comment: So if I add a document with push:false then remove it without push:false, will the document be marked dirty?

Comment: The answer above explains how you can check if the document is marked dirty or not (`getAllDirty`, `getPushRequired`) after a series of operations (e.g. `add` -> `remove`).

Comment: I know how to get the answer to my question myself, I asked it because I hoped someone would know it off the top of this head...